# Duda para ocultar algunos campos en ireport?

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports, condiciones, ireport

Que tal.
Soy algo nuevo con el uso de ireport, ya tengo creado el reporte con el query y todo funciona bien pero ocupo que cuando la suma total de la fila de "estados" sea igual a 0 no imprima estos campos.(En una fila tengo 3 campos: 1 label con el titulo de la fila, un $Field con el valor de esa fila y un $P con el total de esa fila). Me pareció leer sobre la expresion print when expression pero no logro hacerlo, agradecería mucho su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Se ponen condicionantes en la propiedad "Text field expression", para evaluar el variable o parámetro.

```
$P{suma_total}==0 ? ("") :  $P{suma_total}
```